# How do I change the text size in a Label widget? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, label

In python 3.4 using Tkinter, how do I change the text size in a label widget?

So far I have tried

```
label_one = Label(root, text = 'Hello', size = '50')
```

and

```
label_one.config(fontsize='50')
```

But I am not sure where to start and I can't find anything saying how to do it.

Comment: What code do you have so far, what have you tried?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try passing `width=200` as additional paramater when creating the Label.

This should work in creating label with specified width.

If you want to change it later, you can use:

```
label.config(width=200)
```

As you want to change the size of font itself you can try:

```
label.config(font=("Courier", 44))
```

Comment: This changed the width of the box the label is in, not the size of the text itself.

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please share what all different fonts can be used?

Comment: Hello Anurag.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/ may have font choices you can use.