# How to Choose specific data from a readonly text box using tkinter?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I've written come code that selects certain data from a sqlite3 database and outputs them as follows:

```
2017-06-05 test 09:00:00 11:00:00
2017-06-12 test 09:00:00 11:00:00
2017-06-19 test 09:00:00 11:00:00
2017-06-26 test 09:00:00 11:00:00
```

I want to get the dates, and change them so they are a heading for the other data.
How would I go about selecting the dates and making them headers?

Example of what I want;

```
2017-06-05 (in larger font)
name of timeslot: test 
start time: 09:00:00 
end time: 11:00:00
```

code that handle the search function:

```
def searched():
    Main_Screen.configure(state = 'normal')
    Main_Screen.delete('1.0', END)
    searched_for = search.get()
    timeslot = cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM dates WHERE Name = (?)''',(searched_for,))
    list1 = list(cursor.fetchall())
    cursor.execute('''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dates WHERE Name = (?) ''',(searched_for,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    output_text = '\n'.join([' '.join(row) for row in list1])
    Main_Screen.insert(tkinter.END, output_text)
```

Comment: "making them headers" are you talking about html headings or?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us exactly how the output data will look for that example.

Comment: sorry, should of specified. I want the each date to be a larger font size and above the rest of the data. If that's what you mean by html then yes, however I'm not using html in my code.

Comment: so you are using python to access sqlite data, then how are you displaying the results? in a console? website, maybe any app?

Comment: You still haven't specified it adequately. You've only done one of the rows, the rest of the data is missing and we can't tell where you want it to go. We also need to know how you plan to output this thing, because Python is not really for printing things in different sizes.

Comment: I am using a text box that Is readonly until I put the query in. I would put the code here but it doesn't like it.

Comment: but a text box where? what is the interface?

Comment: I am using a tkinter textbox

Comment: ah, now we are getting somewhere

Comment: forgot to mention that, appologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get it line by line and do the following:

```
print line.split()[0]
print "name of time:", line.split()[1]
print "start time:", line.split()[2]
print "end time:", line.split()[3]
```

Comment: I'm using Main_Screen.insert as the way to output to the textbox. I'm stuck as I'm using a search function to get any records with a searched name. So for 'test' there is four results. Can I use line.split for that aswell, even if I don't know how many results I will get?

Comment: this might help in modifying font sizes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685308/how-do-i-change-the-text-size-in-a-label-widget-python-tkinter

Comment: @The4thIceman thanks for the suggestion. Ive edited the question to show the code that outputs the query onto the page, to see if that helps answer the other part of the question about selecting just the date.