# Tkinter Label center text set text to start from top left

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a GUI for my application with Tkinter, and when I create a Label, the text is always at the center of the label, is there a way to set the text to start from the top left ?

```
big_text_area = Label(self.master, text='Hello, World!', width=70, height=25, bg='white', foreground='black')
big_text_area.place(x=380, y=30)
```

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: Read up on [Tkinter.Label.config-method - options `anchor=`, `compound=`, `justify=`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method)

Comment: @stovfl Thanks! I solved it by setting `anchor=NW` in the `config` function of the `Label`

Comment: Here's a [working link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112020335id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method) to replace the one in @stovfl's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61715190/tkinter-label-center-text-set-text-to-start-from-top-left#comment109166988_61715190).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the position of your label is determined by the `.place()` function. So if you want the label to be at the top left, you should do:

```
big_text_area.place(x = 0, y = 0)
```

[Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_place.htm) and [effbot](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111222928id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) have a documentation for the `.place(`) function and the arguments it takes. Most have default values so keep that in mind.

Another thing I would point out is that the `width` and `height` keyword arguments do not change the size of your text. Rather, they change the rectangular box around your text. This might be the reason why your text is still in the middle even if you set its positions to the top left. [effbot](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112020335id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) again has the details on the `Label` widget.

Just a quick working example: (Python 3.7)

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

master.geometry("200x200") 

# to change text size, use font=("font name", size)
w = Label(master, text="Hello, world!", font=("Helvetica", 22))

# explicitly set the text to be at the top left corner
w.place(anchor = NW, x = 0, y = 0)

mainloop()
```

Font question is also answered in this post: [How do I change the text size in a Label widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685308/how-do-i-change-the-text-size-in-a-label-widget-tkinter)

Comment: I have the main window, and I have  the `big_text_area` `Label` that I want to place it in the positions I specify in the `place` function, it is still not working.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out. Feel free to follow-up if you need to.