# How do I change the size of the button text in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

HEIGHT = 950
WIDTH = 650

root=tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff')
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Credit Score Checker", font=20)
button.place(relx=-0, relheight=1, relwidth=0.27)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Financial Advisor", font=20)
button.place(relx=0.25, relheight=1, relwidth=0.27)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Insurance Planner", font=20)
button.place(relx=0.5, relheight=1, relwidth=0.27)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Goal Setter", font=20)
button.place(relx=0.75, relheight=1, relwidth=0.26)

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

label = tk.Label(lower_frame, text="Summary of finances", bg='grey')
label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0, anchor='n', relwidth=0.9, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the text size in a label widget, python tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685308/how-do-i-change-the-text-size-in-a-label-widget-python-tkinter)
Its basically same method for buttons

Comment: also check https://stackoverflow.com/q/4072150/8321664

Answer (score 0):

Instead of font = 20
**You** can use

```
font = ("Helvetica",20,"bold")
#font=(font-family , font-size , "bold"/"italic")
```

You can also do the following

```
font = "Helvetica 20 bold"
```